# How to commits certain files from VS code to GitHub?

Tags: github

A developer wants to commit only certain files. But unable to commit as it requires clean(staged and committed all changes) working directory.

Answer (score 2):

When in doubt, just use the command prompt.  “git add ” for the things to stage and “git commit -m ” after you’ve added them all.

If you have changes locally, you can “git stash”, make your changes and then “git stash pop” after you committed them.

Comment: I want to push only some of the modified files to remote. And other files should remain unstage.

Comment: @bh22 that’s exactly what jjj is explaining. `git add` the files you want to push, `git commit`, then `git push`. The other files will remain unstaged.

Answer (score 0):

To commit certain files, you need to do the following things as shown below:

```
git status 
git add . // for all files
git add "fileName" // for a specific file
git commit -m "the Message" //change message for commit
```

Then, just use `git push` command.